# Apache Proxy mod_rewrite

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, mod-rewrite

Following [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/securing-node-js-restful-apis-with-json-web-tokens-9f811a92bb52) example, I am running a `node` application that I copied from [here](https://github.com/adnanrahic/securing-restful-apis-with-jwt):

I have set up `Apache 2.` for `VirtualHost`, and as show below, I am `proxying` an internet address to the local `node` application running locally.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/hellomvc-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/hellomvc-access.log common

    LogLevel debug
    ServerSignature Off
</VirtualHost>
```

Using `Postman`, When I try to `POST` to the internet site like this:

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/auth/register/[x-www-form-url-encoded parameters here]
```

I get error:

```
Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request POST /api/auth/register.

Reason: Error reading from remote server
```

Do I also have to do a rewrite on  `/api/auth/register/` and pass the parameters to it in the `<VirtualHost *:80>` section above? In the spirit of something like this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !^www\.mydomain\.fi
RewriteRule /(.*) http://www.mydomain.fi/$1 [redirect=301L]
```

**EDIT 1**

I tried

```
curl -d "name=Ivan&email=idf@xxxx.com&password=secret" -X POST http://localhost:5000/api/auth/register
```

After a long time it comes back with:

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Same thing with

```
curl -d "name=Ivan&email=idf@xxxcom&password=secret" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST http://localhost:5000/api/auth/register
```

EDIT 2

This gets a response back, albeit an error. Progress!

```
curl -d "name=Ivan&email=idf@xxx.com&password=secret" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-url-encoded" -X POST http://localhost:5000/api/auth/register


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Error: Illegal arguments: undefined, string<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Error (native)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Object.bcrypt.hashSync (/var/www/securing-restful-apis-with-jwt/node_modules/bcryptjs/dist/bcrypt.js:189:19)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /var/www/securing-restful-apis-with-jwt/auth/AuthController.js:46:31<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/securing-restful-apis-with-jwt/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (/var/www/securing-restful-apis-with-jwt/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Route.dispatch (/var/www/securing-restful-apis-with-jwt/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/securing-restful-apis-with-jwt/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /var/www/securing-restful-apis-with-jwt/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.process_params (/var/www/securing-restful-apis-with-jwt/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (/var/www/securing-restful-apis-with-jwt/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at jsonParser (/var/www/securing-restful-apis-with-jwt/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:118:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/securing-restful-apis-with-jwt/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at trim_prefix (/var/www/securing-restful-apis-with-jwt/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at /var/www/securing-restful-apis-with-jwt/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Function.process_params (/var/www/securing-restful-apis-with-jwt/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at next (/var/www/securing-restful-apis-with-jwt/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And does the POST work without  the proxy? I mean directly to port 3000. No, you need no rewrites to make proxy work.

Comment: The problem is the server has no GUI so I cannot  use Postman locally, or a browser locally to test 127.0.0.1:3000. There is probably some way to use curl/wget, but I don't know that syntax.

Comment: I see, you can't configure the node server to run on a public IP address just for testing purposes?

Comment: You really should try the POST to the node application directly first, I see no problem in your Apache configuration so my guess is that your node application doesn't do what you are expecting it to do. [CURL](https://gist.github.com/subfuzion/08c5d85437d5d4f00e58) can really help you.

Comment: See EDIT 1. something is wrong - has nothing to do with apache.

Comment: Just to be sure, in your Apache configuration, you use port 3000, in the curl example 5000, are you really checking the right one?

Comment: Also tried curl -d "name=Ivan&email=idf@xxxcom&password=secret" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST http://localhost:5000/api/auth/register

Comment: Yeah I am using the right one. I just chaged it to 5000.

Comment: See EDIT 2. Making progress.

Comment: Well, good luck then, I don't think I can help you with that, I only understand the Apache part here :-).

Comment: I figured it out. Even so, the answer/link of how to use curl is worth the price of admission. Thanks!